# Insert data to tableview from array

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray, populate

I hope this isn't too basic to ask here but I'm stuck (again).

I have an array (populated from a sqlite db) and want to insert those data in an UITableView.

So basically I want my textfields and buttons, and of course my tableview to all reside in the same window.
Most of the examples I find out there is about hardcoding the tableview and populating in the viewDidLoad, which I don't want to and therefore can't use those examples (or rather, they don't work)

This is what I got:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ){
        
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //step through the results
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
            //NSLog(@"Data: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
        }
        
        dataArray  = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        [array release];
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);  //releases the resources associted with the statment
        sqlite3_close(dbHandle);    //close db
//***********here I want something like: "tableview.data = dataArray.data"*******
```

Do anyone have any example to point me to or write down here?

Comment: you need to look at the UITableView documents, in particular at the datasource parts. you need to return the array count from UITableView:NumberOfRowsForSection: and you need to set up the cell in UITableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath: once you have the datasource methods hooked up, you can call [self.tableView reloadData] to update the view if there are changes.

Comment: I have tried some examples with those methods but the final [self.tableView reloadData]... did not do what it is/was supposed to.
thats why I belive that I need som expert help in understanding where I misunderstand the whole thing...

Comment: any reason you are using sqllite over core data?

Comment: no, not really. I dont know coredata and I had my data in sqlite.
not sure wich is better...

Comment: I would recommend using core data on the iphone unless there is a good reason not to, you can use NSFetchedResultController objects to manage most of the tableView bits for you, and i think its already in the apple templates iirc.

Comment: I was thinking the other way... I need a good reason to switch :-)
I know sql pretty good... and I dont know if there is any limitations in coredata but I have 220.000 records in my sqlitedb

Comment: Core data is sqllite backed, it is more of an object graph than a db, but the Xcode cd tools are one reason,ease of migration is another. Being able to get properties like this [cdObject name] is quite nice. There are reasons to use straight sqllite, but 9 times out of 10 core data is a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

actually I have revised the problem... the population works after modification.
But the problem that I seemed to have from the beginning (wich I thought was the root of the problem) is that the table fills up the whole window.

I read somewhere that I could make a subview... but wouldnt that make another window?
can I make a subview within my current window (tableview on half that window)?